# When interest rates are historically and exceptionally low why are businesses still acting negatively to their increase?

Tags: monetary-policy

Usually when interest rates rise businesses cannot borrow so the amount of capital they have available goes down which then means they hire fewer people and wages go down so inflation goes down.

This is why businesses react badly to rate increases since they cause recessions. However, rates this time around are at historic lows. They're lower than anything they've ever been. So why are increases still causing a panic which are reflected in the stock market.